# May I know why my edit is rejected?

Tags: support, editing

I have proposed [an edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19976) to a question

[Are there temples where viswaksena is the main deity?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26538/9125)

The summary I provided is

> Corrected the name Vishwaksena and also proper formatting.

I corrected the formatting, added the article link from where the user has copy pasted the article. I also corrected the name of Vishwaksena. It is not Viswaksena.

Still the edit was rejected saying it *improved nothing and harms readability*. Actually, it improved the readability of the post with proper formatting.

Why is this rejected? I ask the community the reason it is rejected.

Comment: BTW changing S to Sh in say Shiva is not exactly "correction of spelling" because the word is not an English word. It is just about making it more perfect according to some transliteration schemes

Comment: @Rickross Did you see my complete edit? The word is Vishwaksena not Siva or Viswaksena. There is much difference in it. sa and Sha are two different letters. Changing letters changes the name dhatu in the word and changes the meaning of the name of the deity. The one I added It is simplified transliteration. Formatting is the important thing I proposed is formatting. Site has definite rules on how to format your posts and attributing to the source which the OP didn't.

Comment: That's what i am saying.. ur edit is based on transliteration.. that's a minor or most trivial edit .. we can't base our edits solely on transliteration.. regarding formatting i am not commenting anything..

Comment: My edit is not based on transliteration. It is formatting and correcting the name. That's not a trivial edit. Proper transliteration makes non English words understand better. It is a form of spelling or Grammar correction only.  Even in any transliteration, Viswaksena is wrong.  It should be Vishvaksena or Vishwaksena in simplified.  It is proper edit because it is correcting the name. Shiva and Siva are different because श is used for it. Some pronounce it as स . But for Vishwaksena, it is ष , a different letter. Even now, the tag name 
 is wrong. No user bothered to create a proper tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This proposed edit is a valid edit as it corrected the spelling of the name, added source of the paragraph along with link. Without this, it was plagiarized content. As plagiarism isn't allowed, I added the link and added formatting.

Even though the edit was rejected in the review, it was [approved](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19976) by post author.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of those who thought it didn't add to the content. All information was already provided by the OP. The problem with a lot of SE "reasons" as they are defined is that either they insufficiently capture the whole thought process or they overkill.

In your case, the correction of spelling is welcome but the others were unnecessary IMO. Please go ahead and correct the spelling once again. I will approve right away if it pops up in my queue.

Comment: I didn't downvote because I can't.Your reason for rejection isn't substantial.There are no opinions while reviewing.There are set of rules whether or not to approve or reject an edit. If you are not sure, you should skip it.Formatting is an important part in the edit and a proper reason for edit on SE. As long as you are on the site, you should follow those rules for reviewing.Personal opinions don't matter while reviewing. "All information was.."  OP provided nothing but copy paste. There are definite rules against plagiarism.Source _must_ be added. So, I added it. See output under markdown.